# LiveData Observer in BindingAdapter

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-livedata

It's possible to make `BindingAdapter` with `LiveData` Observer call?
I need `LifecycleOwner` to call LiveData Observer.

The BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:progressBarObserver")
fun setProgressBarObserver(progressBar: ProgressBar, observer: MutableLiveData<Boolean>) {
    observer.observe({lifecycle_here}, Observer {
        if (it) {
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    })
}
```

`{lifecycle_here}` show that I need to put a LifecycleOwner on LiveData observe Call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `BindingAdapter` with `LiveData`, you don't put `LiveData` as a parameter. Just put livedata's type directly.

```
@BindingAdapter("app:progressBarObserver")
fun setProgressBarObserver(progressBar: ProgressBar, isVisible: Boolean) {
    if (isVisible) {
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

**layout_my.xml**

```
<ProgressBar
    ...
    app:progressBarObserver=@{viewModel.progressBarVisibility}
    ...
```

**MyViewModel.kt**

```
class MyViewModel {
    ...
    val progressBarVisibility = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(true)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wooow, that's it!